# AWS - Automate file creation in EC2 Linux

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

In my new architecture, i've to automate multiple thing for instance creation.
One of them is to create a conf file in a NGINX server while a new instance is created with CloudFormation.

I was thinking about generate a Lamdba function with env variables (IP and DNS) which will create the file in the NGINX server. In my idea, the lambda will be start with a SNS event but i'm not sure if that's possible and how to do it (or if there's a better way to do it)

There's how I create the lambda via CloudFormation :

```
DemoLambda:
    Type: 'AWS::Serverless::Function'
    Properties:
      Handler: lambda_function.lambda_handler
      Events: ? I've to call the SNS here 
      Runtime: python3.8
      CodeUri: s3://MYBUCKET/Demo-Lambda.zip
      Description: ''
      MemorySize: 128
      Timeout: 3
      Role: 'arn:aws:iam::000000000:role/My-role'
      Environment:
        Variables: 
            DNSName: DNSName01
            IP: 10.0.0.1
```

There's a better way or another AWS service to do that ?

Thanks :)

Comment: What about just putting the config file in S3 and pulling it down onto the server when the server starts up? Or you could use something like Ansible and script the whole process

Comment: I thought about pull the file from my S3 but the IP and DNS will be different for each new  instances so as i've read it's not possible to create or edit a S3 object via cloudformation

Comment: Why don't you use user_data for that?

Comment: Yeah in fact it works so easily with user_data

I think that will be the plan :)